# Webdriver. Click on Canvas element by coordinates

Tags: ruby, canvas, selenium, webdriver

I have canvas element on my page and i want to click on some part of it.
I know, that I must use ActionBuilder to do this, so I tryed this code:

```
element = driver.find_element(:xpath, canvas_xpath)
action.move_to(element, 100, 100).click.perform
```

But this code only click in center of canvas element and don't move mouse in any way.

Is there any other possible way to move mouse to some coordinates?
(Don't mention AutoIT scripts - I develop under Linux)

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem in IE. ShockwaveNN's code works for me in Firefox and Chrome. I think the problem is that "click" clicks in the middle of the element. Below is the documentation in action_builder.rb:

```
  #
  # Clicks in the middle of the given element. Equivalent to:
  #
  #   driver.action.move_to(element).click
  #
  # When no element is passed, the current mouse position will be clicked.
  #
  # @example Clicking on an element
  #
  #    el = driver.find_element(:id, "some_id")
  #    driver.action.click(el).perform
  #
  # @example Clicking at the current mouse position
  #
  #    driver.action.click.perform
  #
  # @param [Selenium::WebDriver::Element] element An optional element to click.
  # @return [ActionBuilder] A self reference.
  #
```

According to this and my conclusions, it should just be to execute these actions in two lines like:

```
element = driver.find_element(:xpath, canvas_xpath)
driver.action.move_to(element, 100, 100).perform
driver.action.click.perform
```

or

```
element = driver.find_element(:xpath, canvas_xpath)
driver.action.move_to(element).perform
driver.action.move_by(100, 100).click.perform
```

Sadly, none of this works (for me in IE) : (

Comment: I solved my problem in remote IE with this:
`Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities::internet_explorer(:javascript_enabled => true, :native_events => true)`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `action.move_to(element).move_by(100, 100).click.perform` ?

Answer (score 0):

The click occurs at the center of the target element (see comments 3 and 5 http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3578)

Commands: http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/commands.rb
ActionBuilder: http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/action_builder.rb

Comment: Writing answer with a link is not a real answer because as the link will be changed/removed the answer will be finished.